# Error in Reading Internal temperature sensor in stm32f042

Tags: stm32

The program to read the Internal temperature and V_battery voltage using ADC in STM#2F042 is as follows:

```
#include "main.h"


#define I2C_ADDR                            (0x40<<1);

#define V_Ref                                   3.3

#define RESOLUTION                      255 

#define TEMP30_CAL_ADDR             ((uint16_t*)((uint32_t*)0x1FFFF7B8))

#define TEMP110_CAL_ADDR            ((uint16_t*)((uint32_t*)0x1FFFF7C2))

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc;

float internal_temp;


uint8_t index1=0;

uint32_t adc_value[2];


float V_bat;


void SystemClock_Config(void);

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

static void MX_ADC_Init(void);


void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)

{

    if(__HAL_ADC_GET_FLAG(hadc,ADC_FLAG_EOC))

        {

             adc_value[index1]=HAL_ADC_GetValue(hadc);

             index1++;

        }

    if(__HAL_ADC_GET_FLAG(hadc,ADC_FLAG_EOS))

        {      

        internal_temp = adc_value[0];

        internal_temp -= (int32_t) *TEMP30_CAL_ADDR;

        internal_temp *= (int32_t)(110-30);

        internal_temp /= (int32_t)(*TEMP110_CAL_ADDR - *TEMP30_CAL_ADDR);

        internal_temp += 30; 

        V_bat=(float)adc_value[1]*V_Ref/RESOLUTION;
             
            index1=0;

            
        }
}


int main(void)
{
 HAL_Init();

SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();

  MX_ADC_Init();

  
  MX_TIM2_Init();


  
 
    
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc);

  while (1)
  {
           
 }
}
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)

{


  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  hadc.Instance = ADC1;

  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;

  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;

  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;

  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;

  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;

  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;

  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;

  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;

  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;

  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;

  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;

  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;

  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)

  {
    Error_Handler();

  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
  */

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR;

  sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;

  sConfig.SamplingTime =ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5 ;

  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)

  {

    Error_Handler();

  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
  */

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_VBAT;

  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)

  {

    Error_Handler();

  }

}
```

This is the code I have written (generated from Cubemx.) It will not get the proper value for internal temperature and V_bat (battery voltage).

Can someone please tell me the error/problem in the code, especially in the callback function?

Comment: ...and `adc_value` is what? ...and `index1` is what? Is the ADC using little endian?

Comment: `((uint16_t*)((uint32_t*)0x1FFFF7B8))` should be `((volatile uint16_t*)0x1FFFF7B8u)`. Optionally `(*(volatile uint16_t*)0x1FFFF7B8u)` so you can use it just like a variable.

Comment: Anyway, you need to provide the full code and not just bits and pieces. Variable declarations of all variables involved is fundamental in order to understand the code.

Comment: Few quick notes. The `ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5` feels too short time for sampling it. Use huge value for testing, or look into datasheet for exact value. Also, sometimes the internal channels such as Vref and temperature must be enabled explicitly (they are powered off to save power by default). I found such reference in one of the function comments in the HAL source.

Comment: i have changed `ADC_SAMPLETIME_239CYCLE_5` but the result is not chnaged,the measured temperature is still 343.xxx values